# Is there a way to get a value of a javascript variable in a HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html

I know this sounds stupid and pointless but I am trying to make a website which finds an email address from the entered initial and surname of a person for my workplace. It just has 2 text input fields, one for the initial and one for the surname. My JavaScript joins these with the layout of the email and sets it as the variable "email". How would I set this to a button's href tag using "mailto:"? I tried using `onmouseover="this.href = 'mailto:'+email;"` yet it just returns `undefined;‎`

```js
function buildEmail() {
  var initial = document.getElementById("initial").value;
  var surname = document.getElementById("surname").value;
  var email = initial + surname + "@[emaildomain.com]"
}
```

```html
<h1>Enter the first initial</h1>
<br>
<input type="text" id="initial" />
<br>
<h2>Enter the surname</h2>
<br>
<input type="text" id="surname" />
<br>
<button>
  <a onClick=myFunction() onmouseover="this.href = 'mailto:'+email">Click to send email</a>
</button>
```

Comment: Now that we have the description of the code, could we have the code please? :)

Comment: You can pass email variable in window to get it, using `window.email`

Comment: email is a scoped to the function, it is not global. You do not create the variable until you click also, but you use mouseover so it will read it before the click.....

Comment: @epascarello ah ok thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you have is you have the buildEmail which is not called. And the fact when it is called, the variable email is a scoped to the function so it is not global.

Just call the function onmousedown and set the href so the click will cause the mailto to fire.

```js
function buildEmail(event) {
  var initial = document.getElementById("initial").value;
  var surname = document.getElementById("surname").value;
  var email = initial + surname + "@example.com"
  event.target.href = "mailto:" + email;
}
```

```html
<center><h1>Enter the first initial</h1>
<br>
<input type="text" id="initial" />
<br>
<h2>Enter the surname</h2>
<br>
<input type="text" id="surname" />
<br>
<button><a onmousedown="buildEmail(event)">Click to send email</a></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Edited after code was provided by OP.

You're running into conflicts because `email` is both the name of your element and the name of your variable. Try changing one of them.

Also, your `email` variable is going out of scope once the `buildEmail` function ends (outside the function, that variable doesn't exist). One commenter recommended setting a property on window, which would be accessible globally.

Comment: Oh ok thank you but now it just returns "undefined" :/

Comment: going to take more than that

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to answer without all the information.

Comment: I just used the one function he gave and made those variables accessible by the html he showed us @Matthias

Answer (score 0):

The scope of things are very important.. the variables you declare in `buildEmail` are only "seen" by that function.. if you want those variables to be accessible to another function.. in browsers.. `window` can be used

```
function buildEmail() {
  window.initial = document.getElementById("initial").value;
  window.surname = document.getElementById("surname").value;
  window.email = initial + surname + "@[emaildomain.com]"
}
```